# Type Agnostic class to call generic and non-generic methods within generic class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T> where T : class
{
    public GenericClass()

    public GenericClass(Entity e)

    public IQueryable<T> GenericMethod1()

    public IEnumerable<T> GenericMethod2()

    public T NonGenericMethod1(T t)
}
```

The class works great; however I'm starting to run into issues where I have to instantiate another instance of GenericClass for every type T I want to use, and it's getting a little crazy.  Is there some sort of abstraction I can create to simplify this?

I was heading in this direction, but I can't tell if this is the right choice or if there is a better design pattern I could use; plus, the two invoke calls are not working correctlly at all.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Type type;

    public object Invoke(string method, object obj)
    {
        type = obj.GetType();

        MethodInfo m = typeof(GenericClass<>).GetMethod(method);

        var result = new object();

        if(m.IsGenericMethod == true)
            result = m.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
        else
            result = m.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });

        return result;
    }
}
```

TIA

Comment: It may be obvious to you, but it's completely unclear to me: what are you doing?

Comment: Is object obj an instance of GenericClass<T> or of T?

Comment: @dlev - obj is an instance of T. @dtb - I'm trying to have a single class which I can instantiate once, and then call any of the methods in GenericClass, setting the type by passing it in instead of having to instantiate a different instance of GenericClass for every type I need.  I'm not sure if it's possible, but it would certainly make my life easier if I could at this point in my code base...

Comment: Have you considered using a dependency injection framework? This is what DI does. A good framework will search your code on startup and auto-magically register everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however I'm starting to run into issues where I have to instantiate another instance of GenericClass for every type T I want to use, and it's getting a little crazy

It's hard to guess without some implementation of GenericClass... but I see constructors and methods - no properties (and no fields?).

If that's the case, you may want to make GenericClass a static class with static methods.  Then you aren't allowed to instantiate it and you can call the methods directly from the type:

```
public static class GenericClass
{
  public static IQueryable<T> GenericMethod1<T>() where T:class

  public static IEnumerable<T> GenericMethod2<T>() where T:class

  public static object NonGenericMethod1(object t)
}
```

Called by

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = GenericClass.GenericMethod1<Customer>();
IEnumerable<Customer> items = GenericClass.GenericMethod2<Customer>();
Customer c = (Customer) GenericClass.NonGenericMethod1(customerInstance);
```

---

Or perhaps there are properties or fields, but they aren't dependent on T, then you can move the Generic responsibility to the methods instead of the class.

Now you can have an instance, and that instance can handle all of the T's you want to throw at it.

```
public class GenericClass : IGenericClass
{
  public IQueryable<T> GenericMethod1<T>() where T:class

  public IEnumerable<T> GenericMethod2<T>() where T:class

  public object NonGenericMethod1(object t)
}
```

---

I apologize for the generic-ness of this answer, however that is due to the generic-ness of the question.

Comment: I like moving the generic responsibility to the methods instead of the class...I think that'll work.  I'll give it a shot...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this approach will work. The main issue is that you are trying to create the generic method based on the type in order to avoid instantiating an instance of the appropriate `GenericClass<T>`. But the reason your `Invoke`s are failing is that you are passing in `null` as the target object, even though they are instance methods. The way to get them to work is to construct an instance of the appropriate `GenericClass<T>`, but of course this is what you want to avoid.

If you wanted to go this reflaction route (so you'd still have the centralized construction location,) you can do this via reflection with the following code:

```
Type specificType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
var specificInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType);
```

You can then pass in `specificInstance` as the first parameter to `Invoke()`.

Comment: Thanks @dlev!  I'm going to give David B's answer a shot, but if it doesn't work I'll try this next.  thanks!